Parsing a Microsoft PDB file to extract symbols from it?
I have a Microsoft PDB file and I want to extract symbols along with their addresses from it. Are there any libraries or APIs available that I can use to accomplish this task?

The Debug Interface Access (DIA) SDK is the official library for looking up symbols
